# Multiple Terminal Window icons keep adding up randomly

Tags: eclipse, terminal, spring-tool-suite

Multiple Terminal Window icons keep adding up on random days in eclipse sts and I can't remove them. [image: Here] in the image you can see at the top right portion 9 terminal icons are visible. I cant remove them. Tried resetting and closing perspectives.

Comment: did you try a new workspace?

Comment: @MartinLippert After resetting perspective i didn't restart. Restarting it worked. I just had to reset all the perspectives i was using one by one. Your idea would have worked fine too on this.